# Rails: Form isn't saving properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a basic application for practice, you input a movie and when it was rented on. The move form works fine, the title of the movie links to the rental date. But the rentals form doesn't seem to work. I don't get an error or anything, it just doesn't save. I'm assuming the issue is with my create method but I can't figure it out.

movies_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(comment_params)
    if @movie.save
      redirect_to new_movie_path
    end
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :year)
  end

end
```

rentals_controller.rb

```
class RentalsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @rental = @movie.rentals.build
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @rental = @movie.rentals.build(rental_params[:rental_id])
    if @rental.save
      redirect_to new_rental_path(:id => @movie.id)
    end
  end


  def rental_params
    params.require(:rental).permit(:borrowed_on, :returned_on, :movie_id)
  end

end
```

new.html.erb (rentals)

```
Movie: <%= @movie.title %> <%= link_to "back", new_movie_path %>
<hr>

<%= form_for @rental, :url => { :action => :create, :id => @movie.id } do |f| %>
  Borrowed on: <%= f.text_field :borrowed_on %> <br>
  Returned on: <%= f.text_field :returned_on %> <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<hr>

Rentals: 
<% if !@movie.rentals.blank? %>
  <% for item in @movie.rentals %>
    <%= item.borrowed_on %>, <%= item.returned_on %> <br>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  No rentals yet
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb (movies)

```
Enter new movie information <br>


<%= form_for @movie do |f| %>
  Title: <%= f.text_field :title %> <br>
  Year: <%= f.text_field :year %> <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<hr>

List of all movies: <br>
<% if !@movies.blank? %>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <th> Title </th>
      <th> Year </th>
    </tr>
  <% for item in @movies %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= link_to item.title, :controller => :rentals, :action => :new, :id => item.id %> </td> 
      <td> <%= item.year %> </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table

<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :movies do
    resources :rentals
  end

  root 'movies#new'
end
```

rake routes:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                  Controller#Action
        movie_rentals GET    /movies/:movie_id/rentals(.:format)          rentals#index
                      POST   /movies/:movie_id/rentals(.:format)          rentals#create
     new_movie_rental GET    /movies/:movie_id/rentals/new(.:format)      rentals#new
    edit_movie_rental GET    /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id/edit(.:format) rentals#edit
         movie_rental GET    /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id(.:format)      rentals#show
                      PATCH  /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id(.:format)      rentals#update
                      PUT    /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id(.:format)      rentals#update
                      DELETE /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id(.:format)      rentals#destroy
               movies GET    /movies(.:format)                            movies#index
                      POST   /movies(.:format)                            movies#create
            new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)                        movies#new
           edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)                   movies#edit
                movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#show
                      PATCH  /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#update
                      PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#update
                      DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#destroy
                 root GET    /                                            movies#new
```

Comment: roguerat - You can inspect what's the value of @rental, print that value. And try specifying the method= POST or PUT

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should look like this,

```
class RentalsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @rental = @movie.rentals.build
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @rental = @movie.rentals.build(rental_params)
    if @rental.save
      redirect_to new_rental_path(@movie)
    end
  end


  def rental_params
    params.require(:rental).permit(:id, :borrowed_on, :returned_on, :movie_id)
  end

end
```

And your form should look like this

```
<%= form_for [@movie, @rental] do |f| %>
  Borrowed on: <%= f.text_field :borrowed_on %> <br>
  Returned on: <%= f.text_field :returned_on %> <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hm, I get an "Couldn't find Movie with 'id'=" error with this. It highlights this line here "    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])"

Comment: Wait, it should be `params[:movie_id]` and not `params[:id]`, see my edit

Comment: I changed it and I'm still getting the same error. "Couldn't find Movie with 'id'="  on  "@movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])"

Comment: Can you show me the code how you are opening up the form? I mean the link and the controller code associated with it..

Comment: Just updated the original with movies_controller.rb and new.html.erb for movies. Those are all of my controllers and view files now.

Comment: Change `<%= link_to item.title, :controller => :rentals, :action => :new, :id => item.id %>` to `<%= link_to item.title, new_movie_rental_path(item) %>`

Comment: If possible, paste your routes code, so that I could better understand the flow

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem (as you mentioned in the comments) is coming from the `@movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])` so I would say that you have the problem in your `routes.rb`, which should look something like this:

```
resources :movies do
  resources :rentals
end
```

now the link for creating a new `rental` would be `/movies/:movie_id/rentals/new` and the path would be `new_movie_rental`. You can write something like this to link to the new rentals page:

```
<%= link_to new_movie_rental_path(@movie) %>
```

Comment: When I change both my routes and link to this and go to /movies/:movie_id/rental/new I get an `No route matches [GET] "/movies/:movie_id/rental/new"` error. I also tried going to the old path, /movies/new which I assumed wouldn't work now, but I got an error saying `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"rentals", :movie_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:movie_id]` just in case that helps

Comment: @roguerat Replace the `:movie_id` with the ID of an existing `Movie`. Also make sure that you restart your server after changing `routes.rb`.

Comment: Hm, restarted my server and tried something like http://localhost:3000/movies/5/rental/new and a few other numbers. Still getting the same error. I don't have access to anything now too. I used to be able to access my list of movies... The titles were links which I'd click and it would bring me to the rentals form, the only issue I had was it wasn't saving. But now nothing works.

Comment: That seems perfectly fine to me. You can see a list of available routes by executing `bundle exec rake routes`. What error are you getting?

Comment: Hm, I just tried and I didn't get any error. I added it above if that helps.

Comment: I had a typo: rental shoild've been in plural! But I think now you have your answer?

Comment: ahaha but now i'm getting an `undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass` error, highlighting `Movie: <%= @movie.title %> <%= link_to "back", new_movie_path %>`

Comment: Because the movie with that id is not found?

Comment: Hm, but I had at least 10+ movies in there. I tried all the numbers from 1..10, why wouldn't any of them be found?

Comment: I dont know, maybe you created and deleted and created ad nauseam! From now on, its out of the scope of the question.  Find the IDs from your index page.