# Rails: NoMethodError(s). Can't access pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, nomethoderror

I keep getting a NoMethodError regardless of where I try and go. Going to `http://localhost:3000/` gives me an `undefined method new_movie_rentals_path'` error. And going somewhere such as `http://localhost:3000/movies/5/rentals/new` (and there should be an ID of 5, I also tried many other numbers) gives me an `undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass`. So, I'm getting a few routing errors I believe? But I'm not sure.

movies_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(comment_params)
    if @movie.save
      redirect_to new_movie_path
    end
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :year)
  end

end
```

rentals_controller.rb

```
class RentalsController < ApplicationController

  class RentalsController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
      @rental = @movie.rentals.build
    end

    def create
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
      @rental = @movie.rentals.build(rental_params)
      if @rental.save
        redirect_to new_rental_path(@movie)
      end
    end


    def rental_params
      params.require(:rental).permit(:id, :borrowed_on, :returned_on, :movie_id)
    end

  end

end
```

(movies) new.html.erb

```
Enter new movie information <br>


<%= form_for @movie do |f| %>
  Title: <%= f.text_field :title %> <br>
  Year: <%= f.text_field :year %> <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<hr>

List of all movies: <br>
<% if !@movies.blank? %>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <th> Title </th>
      <th> Year </th>
    </tr>
  <% for item in @movies %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= link_to new_movie_rentals_path(@movie) %> </td> 
      <td> <%= item.year %> </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table

<% end %>
```

(rentals) new.html.erb

```
Movie: <%= @movie.title %> <%= link_to "back", new_movie_path %>
<hr>

<%= form_for [@movie, @rental] do |f| %>
  Borrowed on: <%= f.text_field :borrowed_on %> <br>
  Returned on: <%= f.text_field :returned_on %> <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>


Rentals: 
<% if !@movie.rentals.blank? %>
  <% for item in @movie.rentals %>
    <%= item.borrowed_on %>, <%= item.returned_on %> <br>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  No rentals yet
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :movies do
    resources :rentals
  end

  root 'movies#new'
```

movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rentals
end
```

rental.rb

```
class Rental < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                  Controller#Action
    movie_rentals GET    /movies/:movie_id/rentals(.:format)          rentals#index
                  POST   /movies/:movie_id/rentals(.:format)          rentals#create
 new_movie_rental GET    /movies/:movie_id/rentals/new(.:format)      rentals#new
edit_movie_rental GET    /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id/edit(.:format) rentals#edit
     movie_rental GET    /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id(.:format)      rentals#show
                  PATCH  /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id(.:format)      rentals#update
                  PUT    /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id(.:format)      rentals#update
                  DELETE /movies/:movie_id/rentals/:id(.:format)      rentals#destroy
           movies GET    /movies(.:format)                            movies#index
                  POST   /movies(.:format)                            movies#create
        new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)                        movies#new
       edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)                   movies#edit
            movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#show
                  PATCH  /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#update
                  PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#update
                  DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#destroy
             root GET    /                                            movies#new
```

Comment: Please run `rake routes` and post the results.

Comment: Just added to the original post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: Form isn't saving properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209602/rails-form-isnt-saving-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `new_movie_rental_path`

Also you can check the convention here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Hm, I changed it and I get an `No route matches [GET] "/movies/2/rental/new"` error. And that's when I go to the address `http://localhost:3000/movies/2/rental/new`. The thing is I used to be able to access all of these pages, but then I changed my routes and links to essentially nest rentals within movies. Now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Where you call **new_movie_rentals_path** try to call **new_movie_rental_path**

Ensure that Movie was found in your **new** action at your **RentalsController**